# How to get brother node and set value on javascript change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to preview an image before upload. In my case, it's have a bit of input tag, if I using attribute to catch the node and set value, all the nodes will show the same picture.

```
        @foreach($products as $item)
        <tr>
           <th><input class='imgInp' type="file" name="icon"/><img src ='' alt="" class='thumb'/></th>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

I try to using event.target(input) to catch the brother node(img) and set value, but it's not work

```
    function readURL(input){
    if(input.files && input.files[0]){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){
            $(e).next().attr('src', e.target.result);      
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
$('.imgInp').change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
$(e).next().attr('src', e.target.result);
```

change it to:

```
$(input).next().attr('src', e.target.result);
```

Moreover, I assume you are adding rows to the table body. So, change the th element with a td.

```js
function readURL(input){
    if(input.files && input.files[0]){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){
            $(input).next().attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$('.imgInp').change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

```css
.thumb {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input class='imgInp' type="file" name="icon"/><img src='' alt="" class='thumb'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input class='imgInp' type="file" name="icon"/><img src='' alt="" class='thumb'/></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```